# How to use my scanner in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, scanner

I just connected my Genius Vivid-1200TA scanner to my laptop USB port, now how use it?
In windows, there was a software and driver available for the device. The software has many good features to use the scanner. But I do not know how to use it in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: `lsusb|grep [s,S]canner` shows: `Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05da:3021 Microtek International, Inc. 1200dpi Scanner`-- But programs such as **Simple Scan** or **AquireImage** could not detect scanner and say no scanner is available or similar errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gscan2pdf obtainable free from the Ubuntu Software Centre or simple scan are often good starting points for using scanners under Ubuntu 'straight from the box' without the need to download additional drivers.

Comment: **gscan2pdf** is good software for scanning documents and books pages. But, pPlease look at my comment under the question. The scanner is not detected by **gscan2pdf** as well as other programs.

Comment: I think your recommendation is good and I should ask about my problem in a new question and I did: http://askubuntu.com/questions/584687/scanner-is-conncected-but-not-detected-by-programs

Answer (score 4):

I use xsane, which is intuitive and required no additional drivers (for my scanner; your mileage may vary).