# Scanner is listed under lsusb command, but not detected by scanning programs

Tags: scanner

I connected my Genius Vivid-1200TA image scanner to my laptop USB port running Ubuntu 14.04. `lsusb | grep -i scanner` shows that it is connected and detected by the system:

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05da:3021 Microtek International, Inc. 1200dpi Scanner
```

But programs such as **AquireImage**, **Simple Scan** and **gscan2pdf** do not detect the device and say that no device is detected.

Comment: Looking [here](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-backends.html) I can see that there exist drivers for Genius Vivid 1200 X/XE. No TA is mentioned, however maybe the ones for X/XE works. Installing `libsane` and `libsane-extras` should install them and you may try. Note: you probably already have `libsane` installed, since it is a dependency of simple scan, but you may miss `libsane-extras` which probably contains the driver you need.

Comment: @Bakuriu I installed `libsane-extras` and `libsane` was installed before. But no success!

Comment: Ive had nothing but hassle using any scanner I've tried on Linux. :(

Comment: @Bakuriu In the [link](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-backends.html) you supplied, I found VID/PID of my device: [ScanMaker 3880](http://www.sane-project.org/unsupported/microtek-scanmaker-3880.html)  `USB  0x05da/0x3021  Unsupported  Unsupported. SQ113 chip. See link for more details.` But it is listed under Microteck (**Not Genius**) and has **Unsupported** status! Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is linux. Where there is a will, there is a way. 
ok, do you know what the device is in /dev/? figure that out first.
Since your device shows up in lsusb, then it is almost certainly in dmesg.
Unplug your scanner.

```
sudo dmesg --clear
```

plug in your scanner

```
$dmesg
```

you should see the device name in dmesg. /dev/scanner I have no idea what it will be. Post back with dmesg if you need help figuring it out.

optional step: you can see if the device is listed:

```
$scanimage -L
```

Next, you will try to scan using the command line program scanimage and the device name:

```
$scanimage -d /dev/scanner
```

or

```
$scanimage -d /dev/scanner --quick-format Letter --resolution=600
```

if it kinda works but you want to do something else, try reading `$scanimage --help` or `man scanimage`

Try that and post back errors you may encounter.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. `$dmesg` output is `[63468.743256] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[63468.838042] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=05da, idProduct=3021
[63468.838052] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[63468.838058] usb 2-1.2: Product: USB Scanner               
[63468.838063] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
`.  No device is added to `/dev/` folder. Number of items is the same before and after connecting the scanner!